# How to save information from an SQL query to a variable

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, express

I'm trying to save the information I get from my inmatefirst column with my SQL query into the variable "first'. I was wondering what the correct syntax/approach was to doing this.

```
let sql = `SELECT * FROM inmates WHERE inmatefirst = ? AND inmatelast = ? AND dob = ?`;
let query = db.query(sql, [search.first, search.last, search.dob], (err, result) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  if (result.length != 0) {
    res.render(path.resolve('./myviews/modify'), {
      good: 'Person Found - Please Enter Updated Information',
      first: result.inmatefirst,
      last: result.last,
      dob: result.dob,
      sex: result.sex

    });
  });
});
```

Comment: `mysqli` is a PHP library, what does that have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: `first` isn't a variable, it's an object property.

Comment: `result` is an array of all the rows that were selected. You're trying to access it as a single object.

Comment: Use `result[0].inmatefirst`

Comment: You obviously knew this, since `result.length` only makes sense for an array.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL says, in part, this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM inmates WHERE inma...
```

You've asked for every column from the table. That can make life confusing.

Instead, spell out the columns you want.  Your Javascript indicates that you want these ones:

```sql
SELECT inmatefirst, last, dob, sex FROM inmates WHERE inma...
```

(It's possible that is the wrong set of columns. Check it.

Then, as @barmar pointed out, use `result[0].first` etc, because `result` is an array of objects, one for each row of your resultset.